# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int \"-12\"

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I've been trying to fix this bug and I haven't been able to figure it out. I know this is similar to some of the other threads I've seen on here but I've verified it's not a typo and that the issue isn't with an incorrect data type. Would really appreciate the help and for someone to point out what i'm missing here. Thanks!

[image: Here's the mutation]
[image: Here's the code for the mutation]

Edit: Here's the stack trace

```html
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int \"-12\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 8,
                    "column": 27
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED",
                "exception": {
                    "stacktrace": [
                        "GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found Int \"-12\".",
                        "    at syntaxError (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/error/syntaxError.js:15:10)",
                        "    at Parser.expectToken (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1413:40)",
                        "    at Parser.parseName (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:98:22)",
                        "    at Parser.parseObjectField (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:591:21)",
                        "    at Parser.item (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:575:21)",
                        "    at Parser.any (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1485:26)",
                        "    at Parser.parseObject (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:580:20)",
                        "    at Parser.parseValueLiteral (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:461:21)",
                        "    at Parser.item (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:553:20)",
                        "    at Parser.any (/Users/vn/Documents/Blockchain/fabric/blockchain-fabric-api/node_modules/graphql/language/parser.js:1485:26)"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have creationTime as a string without quotes, so you need quotes

[image]

change it to this:

```js
creationTime: "2007-12-03R10:15:30Z",
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! Must have missed it when I switched from a different value.